# Update API content on webpage with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update content from a weather service API on my webpage by using XMLHttpRequest.

Unfortunately i'm new to using this javascript functionality. I have looked through the mozilla documentation but I am still a little confused of how I need to go about updating the info from the API on my webpage.

My Javascript which includes the refresh function and the addWeather function. The refresh function is suppose to refresh the api information on my website every hour on the hour(which makes use of the xmlhttprequest that i need help on). addWeather function adds the API information to the html and it works well indeed.

Here is the Javascript:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {        

    //populate the weather 
    addWeather();

    //refresh the page every hour
    setInterval(refreshPage(), 3600000);

}

//refresh the page information every hour 
function refreshPage(){
    //make new request to the webservice
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = addWeather();

}

//add the weather info from the weather service
function addWeather(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/6368023a57d122c7/geolookup/conditions/q/DominicanRepublic/Barahona.json",
                  dataType : "jsonp",
                  success : function(parsed_json) {
                      var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
                      var temp = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_c'];
                      var weather = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather'];
                      var humid = parsed_json['current_observation']['relative_humidity'];

                      var wind_direction = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_dir'];
                      var wind_speed = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_kph'];
                      var wind_string = wind_direction + " " + wind_speed + " Km/h";

                      document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML = "Weather " + weather;
                      document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Tempurature " + temp + "°C";
                      document.getElementById("hum").innerHTML = "Humidity " + humid;
                      document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = "Wind " + wind_string;                          
                  }
              });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove () from set interval. now you're passing returned value by addWeather and you wan to pass function itself. So:

```
    setInterval(addWeather,3600000)
```

If you're requesting data with XHR it's available as this.responseText. if it's JSON you can parse it with

```
    var r = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
```

inside add weather function, and it's not like that. Proper XHR:

```
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open('GET','your_url_here');
    r.onload = addWeather;
    r.send()
```

again without (). putting () at the end of function executes it and uses returned value, giving just name will asign function itself, and you want to make variable r.onload equal to your function. Because xhr checks onload property and executes it if its a function

after this you don't need jQuery ajax as its just API for XHR and you have already created request, now read value using responseText. So:

fix XHR, remove jQajax and put content of given to jQajax function into addWeather., so addWeather would look like:

```
    function addWeather(){
      var parsed_json=JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
      ... rest of this internal function ...
```

also remember that parsed JSON will be an object so you can use

var location = parsed_json.location.city;

it should be faster

ah, and change addWeather(); in first line (this before set interval) to refreshPage(); as addWeather(); will now crash as it would be executed manually so there wouldn't be `this.responseText` variable (as it'd be called "outside" xhr)

Comment: sorry for many edits, i made few mistakes by writing fron phone :)